# How to scrape images from a aspx page?

Tags: python, html, asp.net, python-2.7, web-scraping

i am trying to **scrape** images from a aspx page i have this code that scrapes images from normal webpage but can't scrape aspx page cause i need to send http post requests to the aspx page i can't figure out how to do that even after reading few threads this is the original code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urlparse
import urllib2
from urllib import urlretrieve
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import re


def thefunc(url, out_folder):

    c = False
```

**i have already defined headers for aspx page and a if statement that distinguished between normal page and aspx page**

```
    select =  raw_input('Is this a .net  aspx page ? y/n : ')
    if select.lower().startswith('y'):
        usin = raw_input('Specify origin of .net page : ')
        usaspx = raw_input('Specify aspx page url : ')
```

**the header for aspx page**

```
        headdic = {
            'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Origin': usin,
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Referer': usaspx,
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
        }
        c = True

    if c:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headic)
    else:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    
    soup = bs(resp, 'lxml')
    
    parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))

    print '\n',len(soup.findAll('img')), 'images are about to be downloaded'

    for image in soup.findAll("img"):
        
        print "Image: %(src)s" % image
        
        filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
        
        parsed[2] = image["src"]
        
        outpath = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)

        try:
        
            if image["src"].lower().startswith("http"):
                urlretrieve(image["src"], outpath)
            else:
                urlretrieve(urlparse.urlunparse(parsed), outpath)
        except:
            print 'OOPS missed one for some reason !!'
            pass


try:
    put =  raw_input('Please enter the page url : ')
    reg1 = re.compile('^http*',re.IGNORECASE)
    reg1.match(put)
except:
    print('Type the url carefully !!')
    sys.exit()
fol = raw_input('Enter the foldername to save the images : ')
if os.path.isdir(fol):
    thefunc(put, fol)
else:
    subprocess.call('mkdir', fol)
    thefunc(put, fol)
```

***i have made few modifications for aspx detection and creating the header for the aspx page but how to modify next i am stuck here***

`***here is the aspx page link***` http://www.foxrun.com.au/Products/Cylinders_with_Gadgets.aspx

***sorry if i am not clear as you can see i am new to programming, the question i am asking is how can i get the images i get from the aspx page when i am clicking the next page button in the browser cause if i can only scrape one page cause the url is not changing unless i send a http post somehow to tell the page to show the next page with new pictures, because the url stays the same i hope i am clear***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using requests by posting to the url with the correct data which you can parse from the initial page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin
from itertools import chain

url = "http://www.foxrun.com.au/Products/Cylinders_with_Gadgets.aspx"


def validate(soup):
    return {"__VIEWSTATE": soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")["value"],
            "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"],
            "__EVENTVALIDATION": soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]}


def parse(base, url):
    data = {"__ASYNCPOST": "true"
            }
    h = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17'}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
    data.update(validate(soup))
    # gets links for < 1,2,3,4,5,6>
    pages = [a["id"] for a in soup.select("a[id^=ctl01_ctl00_pbsc1_pbPagerBottom_btnP]")][2:]
    # get images from initial page
    yield [img["src"] for img in soup.select("img")]
    # add token for post 
    data.update(validate(soup))
    for p in pages:
        # we need $ in place of _ for the form data
        data["__EVENTTARGET"] = p.replace("_", "$")
        data["RadScriptManager1"] = "ctl01$ctl00$pbsc1$ctl01$ctl00$pbsc1$ajaxPanel1Panel|{}".format(p.replace("_", "$"))
        r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=h).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
        yield [urljoin(base, img["src"]) for img in soup.select("img")]


for url in chain.from_iterable(parse("http://www.foxrun.com.au/", url)):
    print(url)
```

That will give you the links, you just have to download the content and write it to file. Normally we could create a *Session* and go from one page to the next but in this case what is posted is `ctl01$ctl00$pbsc1$pbPagerBottom$btnNext` which would work fine going from the initial page to the second but there is no concept of going from the second to the third etc.. as we have no page number in the form data.

Comment: This is the kind of approach i was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

My internet is really bad where I am so I cannot guarantee 100% that this works just as it is but what you want to execute is in between these lines.

This works for any type of page. If I interpreted anything wrong, don't hold back on commenting.

```
import urllib2
from urlparse import urljoin
from urllib import urlretrieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.foxrun.com.au/Products/Cylinders_with_Gadgets.aspx"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
imgs = soup.findAll("img")
image=0
for img in imgs:
    link=urljoin(url,img['src']) #Join relative paths
    urlretrieve(link, "image"+str(image)) #saves image in the folder you execute this
    image+=1 #increments name
```

This will create

`image1`
`image2`
...
`imageN`

Change the target path as you wish

EDIT:

This has nothing to do with `aspx`.

The page links are javascript generated therefore you can't extract a url from it. `urrlib` doesn't handle dynamically generated content so in this case you will have to use a browser emulator, something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org)+`Firefox()`/[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) or you can use [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash). There is also [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/)+ PhantomJS. The possibilities are endless but I'd go with Selenium :)

With these tools you can interact with the page as if you were in a browser (click, scroll, input text to boxes, etc)

Comment: sorry if i am not clear as you can see i am new to programming, the question i am asking is how can i get the images i get from the aspx page when i am clicking the next page button in the browser cause if i can only scrape one page cause the url is not changing unless i send a http post somehow to tell the page to show the next page with new pictures, because the url stays the same i hope i am clear

Comment: @ShantanuBedajna Updated, good luck and if this answer helped you please mark it as correct :)