# How to scrape aspx pages with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, mechanize

I am trying to scrape a site, https://www.searchiqs.com/nybro/ (you have to click the "Log In as Guest" to get to the search form. If I search for a Party 1 term like say "Andrew" the results have pagination and also, the request type is POST so the URL  does not change and also the sessions time out very quickly. So quickly that if i wait ten minutes and refresh the search url page it gives me a timeout error.

I got started with scraping recently, so I have mostly been doing GET posts where I can decipher the URL. So so far I have realized that I will have to look at the DOM. Using Chrome Tools,  I have found the headers. From the Network Tabs, I have also found out the following as the form data that is passed on from the search page to the results page

```
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__LASTFOCUS:
__VIEWSTATE:/wEPaA8FDzhkM2IyZjUwNzg...(i have truncated this for length)
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:F92D01D0
__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEdAJ8BsTLFDUkTVU3pxZz92BxwMddqUSAXqb... (i have truncated this for length)
BrowserWidth:1243
BrowserHeight:705
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$scrollPos:0
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtName:david
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chkIgnorePartyType:on
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtFromDate:
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtThruDate:
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cboDocGroup:(ALL)
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cboDocType:(ALL)
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cboTown:(ALL)
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPinNum:
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtBook:
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPage:
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUDFNum:
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCaseNum:
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmdSearch:Search
```

All the ones in caps are hidden. I have also managed to figure out the results structure.

My script thus far is really pathetic as I am completely blank on what to do next. I am still to do the form submission, analyze the pagination and scrape the result but i have absolutely no idea how to proceed.

```
import re
import urlparse
import mechanize

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class DocumentFinderScraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://www.searchiqs.com/nybro/SearchResultsMP.aspx"
        self.br = mechanize.Browser()
        self.br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 
                               'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7')]

##TO DO

    ##submit form

    #get return URL

    #scrape results

    #analyze pagination


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = DocumentFinderScraper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

Any help would be dearly appreciated

Comment: It is easier to send POST or GET instead of really submitting a form. Pagination can be done by finding the next button and clicking it until it is not found.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393171/how-to-scrap-images-from-a-aspx-page/37401048#37401048

Comment: You can also try to add this to your Python-script: `logger = logging.getLogger("mechanize")
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`. It's found on the debugging-section here: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/ ... (It's three lines, by the way, - unable to format it properly in a comment).

Answer (score 2):

I disabled Javascript and visited https://www.searchiqs.com/nybro/ and the form looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the *Log In* and *Log In as Guest* buttons are disabled. This will make it impossible for Mechanize to work because it can not process Javascript and you won't be able to submit the form.

For this kind of problems you can use Selenium, that will simulate a full Browser with the disadvantage of being slower than Mechanize.

This code should log you in using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

usr = ""
pwd = ""

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get("https://www.searchiqs.com/nybro/")
assert "IQS" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("txtUserID")
elem.send_keys(usr)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```