# Scrape aspx site with python

Tags: python, asp.net, beautifulsoup, urllib2, urllib

I want to download supreme court cases. Below is the code, I am trying:

```
page = requests.get('http://judis.nic.in/supremecourt/Chrseq.aspx').text
```

I am getting below contents in page:

```
u'<html><p><hr></hr></p><b><center>The Problem may be due to 500 Server Error/404 Page Not Found.Please contact your system administrator.</center></b><p><hr></hr></p></html><!--0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234-->\r\n'
```

Is the site not scrapable or do I need to use some other method?

I checked this answer: [How to scrape aspx pages with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546665/how-to-scrape-aspx-pages-with-python) , but the solution is in selenium. 
Is it possible to do it in python and Beautiful soup?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is you are hitting a url which may be no longer served by the server. I am able to get data from all pages. I checked response from scrapy shell as

```
scrapy shell "http://judis.nic.in/supremecourt/chejudis.asp"
```

and using xpath you can retrieve whatever data you want from same page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to open the website though my browser. I'm getting the same response from my browser. Maybe that's why you're getting that response back.